# Workbook recommendation in preparation for Electrical Engineering

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions, laplace-transform, book-recommendation

I'm currently preparing myself for starting my graduate degree in Electrical Engineering. The mathematics courses given are outlined as follows:

**Mathematics 1**

- Real functions
- Continuity, limits, derivatives, integration
- Polar & Cylindrical coördinates
- Complex numbers

**Mathematics 2**

- Laplace transformations
- Solving differential equations and systems
- Convolution products
- Fourier transformation

I've studied elementary mathematics in high school. This was quite a while back however, and want to prepare myself decently for this course. Because of this I am looking for recommendations on decent text- or workbooks on these subjects, tackling them from the ground up. Naturally, practical ones with lots of exercises are preferred.

Secondly; In what specific fields of study are the subjects listed above  contained? This would help me guide my search.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically all fields in science and engineering contain some differential equation. It is difficult to point in any specific direction. 

This looks like bachelor level to me (which would be undergrad), but maybe differs depending on where one studies. Where I live undergrad is bachelor, graduate is master level and postgraduate is Phd / research degree level. What complicates things is that in some countries you don't have to do an MSc but can hop directly from bachelors grade to research studies, then any distinction graduate / post-graduate level get kind of mashed up.

Comment: Correct. I'm entering my masters degree - hence my use of the (translated) term 'postgraduate' was incorrect. I've edited my post above to reflect the proper level.

Answer (score 3):

Schaum's outlines are a great resource and contain lots of exercises to work through. For the "Mathematics 1" categories listed, you could probably find those all in the beginning and advanced calculus outlines. For the "Mathematics 2" categories, Schaum's Outline of Differential Equations will cover part of it. For the rest, I'd recommend Applied Partial Differential Equations by Haberman. Good luck!